# netlink_register_notifier is not available with Network namespace support?

Tags: c, linux, lxc, netlink, linux-namespaces

I could not find functions "**netlink_register_notifier**" or "**netlink_unregister_notifier"** which were used to handle **notification** during events like "**NETLINK_URELEASE**" in current Unix Kernel supporting network namespace that uses netlink_kernel_create(**net**, ...)" function using

```
    register_pernet_subsys
```

So what is the way to handle Netlink notification? like NETLINK_URELEASE?

When userspace process closes or terminates then netlink notifier in Kernel gets invoked where we can handle clear close; Now how to handle this in current Linux kernel which support Network namespace.

For example:

```
static int my_notifier(struct notifier_block *this,
                          unsigned long event, void *ptr)
{
     /* NO CODE HERE other than return*/
     return NOTIFY_DONE;
}


static struct notifier_block nBlk =
{
     .notifier_call = my_notifier,
};

static int __net_init my_netlink_start(struct net *net)
{
    nlsk = kzalloc(sizeof(*nlsk), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!nlsk)
        return -ENOMEM;

    netlink_register_notifier(&nBlk);
    nlsk->sk = netlink_kernel_create(net ...);
    ...
}

static void my_netlink_end(struct net *net)
{
    netlink_kernel_release(nlsk->sk);
    netlink_unregister_notifier(&nBlk);
}
```

Now, If I start lxc by running

```
lxc-start -d -n Container1
```

Then kernel crash but then If I remove the entire notifier both netlink_register_notifier and netlink_unregister_notifier things are working perfectly but now I could not handle user application termination :(

Comment: What version of kernel are you building your code on? These interface are there just fine.

Comment: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=netlink_register_notifier

Comment: @fluter I am using Linux Kernel 3.4 and I could not see any Kernel code making use of it like fib_frontend.c or xfrm_user.c which uses "net" rather &inet_net during netlink_kernel_create;

Comment: Now I added code so that it will help in understanding the real problem;

Comment: I find the issue; I should not call the netlik_register_notifier or netlink_unregister_notifier inside .init or .exit; I should be invoked at module init or exit which calls for register_pernet_subsys();

Comment: Can you show the changes you have done for clarity. Facing a similar issue with dockers.

Comment: @Haswell I don't have the code currently; To fix this issue I removed "netlik_register_notifier" and "netlink_unregister_notifier" from "my_netlink_start" and "my_netlink_end" funcitons respectively because they are not supposed to be called inside those function rather it should be called at function invoking "register_pernet_subsys";  That is this function will be invoked only once during system start and off and not during namespace creation or deletion. I hope this will help you to fix your issue. Thanks